# How can I dynamically do Excel-like operations in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pointers

In Excel, changing the value in one cell can change the values in other cells as formulas are propagated. Also, cells can be updated with new formulas at any time. How can I achieve a similar dynamic functionality inside of a 2-dimensional array created in VBA? The only formula that I need to be able to propagate here is summation, so nothing too fancy. For now, we can assume that there will be no circular references. Suppose also that I am already able to figure out a topological ordering of the spots in the array.

Here is an example with a 2X2 array.

```
Public Sub CanIExcelInVBA()
    Dim my_array(1, 1) As Long
    
    my_array(0, 0) = 1
    my_array(0, 1) = my_array(0, 0) + 1
    my_array(1, 0) = my_array(0, 1) + 1
    my_array(1, 1) = my_array(1, 0) + 1

    my_array(0, 0) = 2
    Debug.Print my_array(1, 1) ' I want this to be a 5, but it's a 4 still.
    
End Sub
```

The last position in the array should update because the value at my_array(0, 0) was changed. Also, the summation formulas that are actually inside of the array will need to be able to be changed programmatically at run-time. This would involve conditional logic with variables already in VBA.

I believe that I could achieve what I want with pointers or by writing my array to the worksheet. I am leaning more towards pointers because I want to limit the amount of time spent reading and writing to the worksheet. I am using 64-bit Excel.

In another part of this project, I am already using the VBA stack implementation that uses pointers that I found here:
https://github.com/Evanml2030/Excel-ArrayFunctions/blob/master/ArrayFunctions.xlsm

The problem is that I don't really understand how his code works or how to modify it to fit my current situation.

Comment: This is far from a simple ask, and if you don't understand the code you're already using it's difficult to see how you could achieve it without someone writing the bulk of it for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_array(i, j)` accesses a value in the array, not pointer.

Also there is no mechanism to propagate recalculation in VBA. If you want to do such a thing, you can use a worksheet in Excel, setting formulas with e.g. `Range("A2").Formula = "=A1+1"` and getting values with `Range("A2").Value` in VBA. Otherwise, you have to reinvent an entire spreadsheet-like system.

Comment: Ok, I will try the reading and writing to the worksheet approach.